# Cannot Launch SharePoint Farm Configuration Wizard

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, I am unable to launch the Farm Configuration Wizard from Central Admin.  The error is:

Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: parent

Can anyone provide some insight on this?  The detailed error message (from the ULS log) is:

> 03/10/2011 11:21:58.86    w3wp.exe
>   (0x143C)
>     0x15E0  SharePoint Foundation
>     Runtime
>     tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   parent    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1..ctor(SPPersistedObject
>   parent)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedChildCollection`1..ctor(SPPersistedObject
>   parent)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdminConfigUtil.DeleteAllExistingDataObjects()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AdminConfigIntro.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) cfa6e917-13f3-4546-81af-bbfc8bf9c7c7

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this problem, the solution for me was to run the SharePoint Product Configuration wizard and disconnect from the farm, then re-run it and connect to the farm.  Crazy, but it worked.